# RaPI as NAS; USB to SATA using Powered USB Hub

Tags: nas

I wish to set up a proper NAS, raid 5.

I'm currently a student, so my idea is as follows:

Get 4x WD-RED 4TB drives, and connect them all via a USB to SATA cable, to a USB hub which I attatch to a Raspberry PI I have laying around.

Aside from the obvious bottle neck of the USB 2.0 interface, (or even the rapi cpu), could this work?

If it works, would I then later be able to get something like a DS416 and re-assemble the raid?

Comment: I haven't experimented, but I think your bottleneck is going to be your Raspberry Pi CPU far before USB is an issue.

Comment: Hm, good point. Might have to experiment on this :)

Comment: Changed my question abit then. Please discard any speed-related bottlenecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Basically you will need to create the NAS from scratch as there is no NAS OS constructed specifically for the RasPI (as far as i know). This is what i would do:

I **Strongly** suggest to test this on a VM *before* using your real hardware.

1. Get a list of services you want to have the NAS perform. Ex: File share (samba/smbd), FTP, SSH ( a *must* for management, remember to not allow root). Those are pretty much the main ones for a NAS.
2. Install `mdadm` on the RasPI. Since the RasPI doesnt have a hardware RAID, it would need a software RAID controller instead.
3. At this point you should have Raspbian or OS of choice, all NAS drives connected and `mdadm` installed. Now we need to verify that the RasPI can see the drives before we do anything else.
4. Run the command `sudo fdisk -l` to list the file systems connected to the RasPI. Make sure they are all available.
5. If all drives are present then we can move onto this tutorial which shows you how to setup a software raid on linux. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04#creating-a-raid-0-array
6. After you get your raid setup you can mount it and copy files on there to test it.

This is pretty much the basic setup. Whatever you want to do with the file system as far as users and permissions and what not, im sure you can figure that part out :). Good luck!

Would also look into OpenMediaVault as its a *REAL* NAS OS built on linux. I have that running with a RAID1 at home ;).

Hope this gives you a head start!

Comment: As i read, OpenMediaVault does have a build for the RaPi :)
But thank you very much for your nice answer

Comment: really? thats cool, i should check that out

Comment: either way, if you use OMV, then you should be fine. Its only if youre doing this from scratch is where you should get some practice beforehand.